# while loop read data from two colums

Tags: shell, while-loop, do-while

In my limited experience with while loop in shell script, i have a requirement to check the remote hosts connection in new public key.

```
cat JOBID_LIST.txt
HLC00101 abc@gbl67543.cloud.uk.hlc
HLC01110 absit@DEU010A.cloud.uk.hlc
HLC02568 abftp@GTB19494.systems.uk.hlc
HLC02590 wbsftp@batch.mose.dev.cloud.hlc
HLC02590 cmul1u11@batch.mose.dev.cloud.hlc
HLC02648 dmlfeat@lmd-fileserver-uat.systems.uk.hlc
HLC02648 dmsftp@lmd-fileserver-uat.systems.uk.hlc


#!/bin/bash
cat JOBID_LIST.txt | while read -r JOBID SFTPHOST
do
   if [[ ${JOBID} != "HLC02648" ]]; then
        ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostkeyChecking=no ConnectTimeout=5 "$SFTPHOST" -i xxxx.pub 'exit 0'
    
           if [[ $? == 0 ] ; then
                echo "Connect to $SFTPHOST in $JOBID in new pubkey successfully."
            else
                echo "Failed to connect to $SFTPHOST in $JOBID in new pubkey "
            fi
   else
     echo "Verify Completely"
     exit 2.
   fi
done
```

For some stange reason, the ssh command breaks out of the while-loop, therefore the third JOBID till the end are ignored.
How could i make it check till the end of file?
Apprciated for your advice.

Comment: `ssh` inherits its stdin from the pipe.  It thus consumes much of the data intended for the while/read loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding a `</dev/null` before the ssh calls will help?

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r JOBID SFTPHOST; do
   if [ "$JOBID" != "HLC02648" ]; then
      </dev/null \
      ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostkeyChecking=no \
          ConnectTimeout=5 "$SFTPHOST" -i xxxx.pub 'exit 0'
      if [ $? = 0 ]; then
         echo "Connect to $SFTPHOST in $JOBID in new pubkey successfully."
      else
         echo "Failed to connect to $SFTPHOST in $JOBID in new pubkey "
      fi
   else
      echo "Verify Completely"
      exit 2
   fi
done < JOBID_LIST.txt
```

Comment: Or you could do `ssh -n`

Comment: Ah. I was not aware of this option. Thanks!